# Dex2oat falhou - erros recebidos no android install/atualização app de .dex permissão negada

Tags: android

Enquanto o aplicativo está atualizando/rodando verifiquei varios erros relacionados ao mesmo problema

> 03-13 19:58:28.772 5605-5611/? E/art: Failed sending reply to
>   debugger: Broken pipe 03-13 19:58:28.822 5619-5619/? E/dex2oat: Failed
>   to create oat file:
>   /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@br.gov.rj.pmerj.policialoficialsv-1@split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk@classes.dex:
>   Permission denied 03-13 19:58:29.242 5634-5634/? E/dex2oat: Failed to
>   create oat file:
>   /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@br.gov.rj.pmerj.policialoficialsv-1@split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk@classes.dex:
>   Permission denied 03-13 19:58:29.292 5639-5639/? E/dex2oat: Failed to
>   create oat file:
>   /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@br.gov.rj.pmerj.policialoficialsv-1@split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk@classes.dex:
>   Permission denied 03-13 19:58:29.337 5643-5643/? E/dex2oat: Failed to
>   create oat file:
>   /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@br.gov.rj.pmerj.policialoficialsv-1@split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk@classes.dex:
>   Permission denied 03-13 19:58:29.382 5647-5647/? E/dex2oat: Failed to
>   create oat file:
>   /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@br.gov.rj.pmerj.policialoficialsv-1@split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk@classes.dex:
>   Permission denied 03-13 19:58:29.427 5653-5653/? E/dex2oat: Failed to
>   create oat file:
>   /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@br.gov.rj.pmerj.policialoficialsv-1@split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk@classes.dex:
>   Permission denied 03-13 19:58:29.477 5657-5657/? E/dex2oat: Failed to
>   create oat file:
>   /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@br.gov.rj.pmerj.policialoficialsv-1@split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk@classes.dex:
>   Permission denied 03-13 19:58:29.527 5661-5661/? E/dex2oat: Failed to
>   create oat file:
>   /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@br.gov.rj.pmerj.policialoficialsv-1@split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk@classes.dex:
>   Permission denied 03-13 19:58:29.572 5665-5665/? E/dex2oat: Failed to
>   create oat file:
>   /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@br.gov.rj.pmerj.policialoficialsv-1@split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk@classes.dex:
>   Permission denied 03-13 19:58:29.617 5669-5669/? E/dex2oat: Failed to
>   create oat file:
>   /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@br.gov.rj.pmerj.policialoficialsv-1@split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk@classes.dex:
>   Permission denied 03-13 19:58:29.662 5681-5681/? E/dex2oat: Failed to
>   create oat file:
>   /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@br.gov.rj.pmerj.policialoficialsv-1@split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk@classes.dex:
>   Permission denied

já tenho permissao de escrever e ler `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE/READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` o que pode ser ?? que permissão é esta que está negada ?

**`AndroidManifest.xml`**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>

<!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
     location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/police"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_splash"
        android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <!-- <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> -->
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity-alias
        android:name=".MainActivity-um"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/police"
        android:label="Vade Mecum"
        android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
        android:targetActivity=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity-alias>
    <activity-alias
        android:name=".MainActivity-dois"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/iconetriball"
        android:label="Tatoo"
        android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
        android:targetActivity=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity-alias>
    <activity-alias
        android:name=".MainActivity-tres"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/iconebode"
        android:label="Zoo"
        android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
        android:targetActivity=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity-alias>
    <activity-alias
        android:name=".MainActivity-quatro"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/iconeplay"
        android:label="Play Songs"
        android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
        android:targetActivity=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity-alias>
    <activity-alias
        android:name=".MainActivity-cinco"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/iconeusa"
        android:label="Usa"
        android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
        android:targetActivity=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity-alias>
    <activity-alias
        android:name=".MainActivity-seis"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/iconewirelles"
        android:label="Wirelles Remote"
        android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
        android:targetActivity=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity-alias>
    <activity-alias
        android:name=".MainActivity-sete"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/alianca"
        android:label="Aliance"
        android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
        android:targetActivity=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity-alias>
    <activity-alias
        android:name=".MainActivity-oito"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/correio"
        android:label="Correio"
        android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
        android:targetActivity=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity-alias>
    <activity-alias
        android:name=".MainActivity-nove"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/email"
        android:label="E-mail"
        android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
        android:targetActivity=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity-alias>
    <activity-alias
        android:name=".MainActivity-dez"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/trabalhando"
        android:label="Em Obras"
        android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
        android:targetActivity=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity-alias>

    <activity
        android:name=".Vademecum"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="br.gov.rj.pmerj.policialoficialsv.MainActivity" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity android:name=".PesquisaActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".SearchResultsActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".VademecumItens"
        android:parentActivityName=".Vademecum" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="br.gov.rj.pmerj.policialoficialsv.Vademecum" />

    <activity
        android:name=".VademecumItemUnico"
        android:parentActivityName=".VademecumItens">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="br.gov.rj.pmerj.policialoficialsv.VademecumItens" />
    </activity>
    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" />
    <activity
        android:name=".AlterarIconeActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_alterar_icone"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="br.gov.rj.pmerj.policialoficialsv.MainActivity" />
        />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".teste"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_teste"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

A partir do Android 6.0 (nível de API 23), os usuários concedem permissões a aplicativos enquanto eles estão em execução, não quando eles são instalados. Essa abordagem otimiza o processo de instalação de aplicativos, pois o usuário não precisa conceder permissões ao instalar ou atualizar o aplicativo. Ela também confere ao usuário mais controle sobre os recursos do aplicativo. Por exemplo, um usuário poderia optar por permitir que um aplicativo de câmera tenha acesso à câmera, mas não à localização do dispositivo. O usuário pode revogar as permissões a qualquer momento na tela Settings do aplicativo.

Segue o exemplo de como solicitar a permissão:

```
/**
 * Verifica a permissão do usuário
 */
private void checkPermission() {
    // Verifica necessidade de verificacao de permissao
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission. WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // Verifica necessidade de explicar necessidade da permissao
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, android.Manifest.permission. WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "É necessário dar acesso de escrita!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission. WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    CODE_PERMISSION_LOCATION);
        } else {
            // Solicita permissao
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission. WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    CODE_PERMISSION_LOCATION);
        }
    }
}
```

[FONTE](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)